# invoking winforms in web application

Tags: asp.net

I have a windows control library having PictureBox and ColorDialog. How can I get it in Web Application? Will u please help me?

Comment: What do you mean "get" it? Convert it to ASP.NET with similar GUI and functionality? Download the EXE to client and execute it? Please be more clear..

Answer (score 1):

You can [host it as ActiveX object](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2005/02/16/hosting-net-winforms-in-ie-the-tabletinspector-goes-online/) but it will work only in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just invoke. Also use it under web application. Try [VisualJS.NET](http://visualjs.net) It lets you design and develop under WinForms and run it under browser.